# Contains CAML query returns only DISTINCT items

Tags: caml-query

I am trying to write a CAML Query that returns all items from the list where in the "Title" field they contain "No Title". (In order to delete them later).

The deletion is done in Csharp.

I have come up with the below query:

```
<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>No Title</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>
```

It there is one item containing "No Title" it works, returns one item.
If there is several items containing "No Title", it only returns one item as long as the fields have the same string.

Is there anything missing to my query?

Comment: Make sure you are writing the query under double quotes as: `camlQuery.ViewXml =
"<View><Query><Where><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>No Title</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";`

Comment: @SohailShaikh Yes it has double quotes.

Comment: Are you certain that the items actually have the "No Title" value? AFAIK this is the display text generated by the "LinkTitle" field (when displayed in the UI) that displays this a fallback text. If the "Title" field is actually empty, you should use "<IsNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNull>" to locate the items in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CAML looks ok. Maybe it is your C# code that is causing the trouble. Have a look at the [sample code here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee534956(v%3Doffice.14)).

Comment: Indeed it was my Csharp code problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code in your query:

```
"<Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNull></Where>"
```

Please upvote if this answer helped you in any way.